# Import Unity Package Into Specific Folder

Tags: unity, unityscript, file, import

Everytime i do import custom `unity` package file, I alwasy get **Messy Folder and files** in root of Asset Folder.

Any Idea how to solve this ?

Many Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is that I always create a new project first where I import the unity package file. I then change the structure of the project as I want it to look in my final project. Finally I select the files i want to export and then i right click on them and choose "Export as UnityPackage",
Open your final project and import your newly created Unity package and voilà.

Comment: how to you deal with updating the re-packaged packages ? (if you do update them that is).  My guess would be that you would repeat the above procedures with any new version on one or more of the packages.

Comment: Late reply: I am afraid I haven't come up with a much better way of doing it than what you describe.